# Implementing AddProximityAlert

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alert, android-pendingintent

New to Android/Java, and I'm playing around with AddProximityAlert(). I have the following block of code below, and keep getting errors. Could someone explain what Eclipse is saying, and how I can resolve the error I'm getting for getBroadcast and registerReceiver?

In the SecondaryActivity.java file, I have 2 broadcast receivers, could that be the reason why?

SecondaryActivity.java:

```
public class SecondaryActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {   

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

.
.
.

lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
float radius = 100f;
long expiration = -1;
final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.example.test";

Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.**getBroadcast**(this, 0, intent, 0);

lm.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, radius, expiration, proximityIntent);

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);

**registerReceiver**(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);

.
.
.

private class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

...

**getBroadcast**: The method getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable for the arguments (SecondaryActivity, int, Intent, int)

**registerReceiver**: The method registerReceiver(SecondaryActivity.ProximityIntentReceiver, IntentFilter) is undefined for the type SecondaryActivity

Comment: Does your `SecondaryActivity` class extend Activity?

Comment: "public class SecondaryActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {" and inside "public class SecondaryActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {" I have a "private class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {"

Comment: I dont think I need another activity, I just want to call a method within the current activity if the proximity alert is triggered... If theres another way to do this I'd like to know! thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are extending a BroadcastReceiver, you need to use:

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)
```

and

```
context.registerReceiver()
```

to reference a Context class.

Also naming a BroadcastReceiver `SecondaryActivity` is a little confusing since `SecondaryActivity` is not an Activity.